# Why does signalr keep a copy of my scope angular when used with stateprovider

Tags: javascript, angularjs, signalr

I have the following code to contact signalr

```
app.service("signalrService", ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    this.votingResultMessages = function (callback) {
        var hub = $.connection.votingHub;
        $.extend(hub.client, {
            votingResultMessage: function (data) {
                $rootScope.$apply(function () { if (callback) callback(data); });
            }
        });
        $.connection.hub.start(function () { });
    }
}]);
```

In my init function off my controller, I have the following:

```
console.log('setup:' + scope.$id);
signalrService.votingResultMessages(function (data) {
    console.log('callback:'  + scope.$id);
    scope.setVotes(data);
});
```

I'm using $stateProvider to navigate within my application and the second time I enter my scope and the signalr fires the callback I get the following:

```
setup:599
callback:244
```

So it seems like the signalr callback from the first time is saved, and the new one is not used, thus nothing works.

What can I do about this?

Seems like storing the scope in a global variable works around it:

```
window.voteScope = scope;
signalrService.votingResultMessages(function (data) {
    window.voteScope.setVotes(data);
});
```

Is this correct?